# How to create private key and public key with web3?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js

I want to create a private key and public key, basically a new account in Ethereum using web3. But I want to generate a private key that is 32 bytes in length. Does anyone know how to generate the same?

I used the following code, but not able to generate a 32 bytes long private key.

```js
web3.eth.accounts.create();
```

Comment: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Private key must be 32 bytes in length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
web3.eth.accounts.create()

address: '0xB9b1415Dbd1B3C9a5890433DF8B2b389445CC6Fa',
  privateKey: '0x498262a4afde2bdd9e1bef3aafc6442ec36ccf167e527457a211118de93346ba',
  signTransaction: [Function: signTransaction],
  sign: [Function: sign],
  encrypt: [Function: encrypt]
```

the private key is here *'0x498262a4afde2bdd9e1bef3aafc6442ec36ccf167e527457a211118de93346ba'*
this is of a 64 hex format.

so the **32 bytes length private key** is
***498262a4afde2bdd9e1bef3aafc6442ec36ccf167e527457a211118de93346ba***

(remove the **0x**)

Comment: do not use this private and public key for transferring tokens, as the private key is available on this public domain, you may incur loss on your assets

Answer (score 2):

Ethereum uses 32 bytes (which is 64 hex characters) long private keys.

You can access the private key generated using the `accounts.create()` method ([docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.2/web3-eth-accounts.html#create)) in the `privateKey` property.

```
const account = web3.eth.accounts.create();
console.log(account.privateKey);
```